# (SP Flash Tool) Recovery.img file too large and causes region overlap message. Safe to Proceed?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, flashtool

I am trying to root my Micromax Canvas Colors 2 A120 running KitKat 4.4.2 using the SP Flash Tools.

During the flashing of a recovery after selecting the Scatter File for my device (I created the Scatter using MTK Droid Tools,) SP Flash Tool throws a message that the selected recovery image (about 6 MB) is too large and causes overlap of regions.

However this doesn't seem to be an error as it lets me continue with the flashing process.

However I did not yet proceed with the flashing process as I am not sure about the warning message. 
Will it be safe to proceed ignoring the region overlap message? Or should I choose another recovery file? I've googled a number of recoveries for my device, but mostly every one of them is of the same size (a few KBs here and there...)

[image: recovery.img is too large and causes region overlap]